# Artifactory login ERROR when user in groups with non-ASCII characters

Tags: artifactory

We've got users unable to login, when they belong to groups in LDAP that contain non-ASCII characters. Seen the behaviour on a couple of groups and removing affected users from these groups allowed them to login - so we're pretty certain that's the problem.
We're on a self-hosted Artifactory 7.11.5, on a Ubuntu 18.04.

console.log contains the story:

```
[ERROR] [29e5228a7103dcec] [                              ] [main                ] - Error: error creating UI session token for user - <<username>>
at Function.createUISessionToken (/opt/artifactory-pro-7.11.5/app/frontend/bin-1.11.5/server/dist/webpack:/src/Services/Access/AccessTokenService.ts:56:20)
[jffe ] [ERROR] [29e5228a7103dcec] [                              ] [main                ] - Error: GRPC error - INTERNAL scope is malformed: applied-permissions/user applied-permissions/groups:"<some groups>> 
bdgæster <-- culprit
<other groups>"
at Function.handleError (/opt/artifactory-pro-7.11.5/app/frontend/bin-1.11.5/server/dist/webpack:/src/Utilities/GrpcErrorUtil.ts:7:20)
at Function.createUISessionToken (/opt/artifactory-pro-7.11.5/app/frontend/bin-1.11.5/server/dist/webpack:/src/Services/Access/AccessTokenService.ts:57:21)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[jffe ] [ERROR] [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - AuthErrorAuthenticateRequest: error onAfterSuccessful login
at Function.validateUserInfoAndAuthenticateRequest (/opt/artifactory-pro-7.11.5/app/frontend/bin-1.11.5/server/dist/webpack:/src/Controllers/Authentication/LoginController.ts:179:19)
```

Anything we can do on our end to sort this out or is that a pure bug to be handled by devs?